# Linked Server dows not work, while direct connection works (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I have 2 Linked servers (B and C) that simply stopped working from my main server (A), and returns me a "Login Timeout Expired" error when I try to test them, but, the server A has access to B and C servers, I can login into the B and C via SSMS in the server A, with the same credentials that the linked server use, but I cannot create the linked server, server A is SQL Server 2012 Standard, servers B and C are SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard.

I used another, smaller server (D), which is also SQL Server 2012 Standard, to test the linked servers to B and C and they worked, so I guess the problem is within A.

In A, I have another linked server to a SQL Server 2008 R2, and it works, just this two.

I tried opening all doors in the firewall, making the linked server by server name and by IP address, creating a new SQL User to make the linked server, none of that worked, my next step is to reboot the server, but I can do that only by nighttime, since A is a production server.

Anyone can help me on this please?

Comment: Did you checked permissions or anything changed recently. Ask your DBA if any modifications done to the user account ?

Comment: I'm the DBA, no changes were done to the user account, I made sure of that this morning